# creating a simple symmetric table in java

Tags: java

I'm currently studying arrays in Java. However, I'm having trouble creating a symmetric table, something like the following:

[image]

Is there a simple solution to create an array like this? This is not homework but for an exam I'm studying for. I want to know how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Here is the code I have:

```
int [][] table = new int [5] [8];
for (i=0;i < 5; i ++)
{
  table[i][0] = i+1;
}

for ( j = 0; j < 4; j ++)
{
   table[ i ][ j ] = ;
}
```

It's not much code, but I don't know how to iterate through it so all the values are symmetric. I have filled the first row with values. I was thinking about looping to 4 in the columns so I'm in the half but then what do I do?

Comment: Please, show us your algorithm

Comment: Is this supposed to be a two-dimensional array, or just a one-dimensional one? Anyway, show us what you have tried so far. We are developers, we want to see code. <g>

Comment: Put the code in your question. You can edit your question. Use the `{}` symbol to turn your code into line-formatted code.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I have done that. I'd be very happy if you can help me out with this, programming is a course I struggle with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a beginning, but doesn't fill all values. You should *nest* your for-loops, and only fill the left part. The right entry can then be mirrored from the left entry. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] table = new int[5][8];

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        {
            // left side entry [row][0..3]
            // each entry is 5 more than the entry left of it 
            table[row][column] = column * 5 + row + 1;

            // right side entry [row][7..4] mirrored from corresponding entry [row][0..3]
            // i.e. column 7 <- column 0, column 6 <- column 1, etc.
            table[row][7 - column] = table[row][column];
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++)
        {
            System.out.format("%4d", table[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
   1   6  11  16  16  11   6   1
   2   7  12  17  17  12   7   2
   3   8  13  18  18  13   8   3
   4   9  14  19  19  14   9   4
   5  10  15  20  20  15  10   5
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I do have one more question, can you please elaborate a bit on this code:

table[i][j] = j * 5 + i + 1;

        table[i][7 - j] = table[i][j];

Why do you use j*5+i+1 and then in the columns table[i][7-j]?

I don't really understand the iteration you use.

Comment: I renamed `i`and `j`. Take a look at your table. If you go from left to right, in the left side, each entry is 5 more than the one left of it. That explains the `column * 5 + row + 1` part. To mirror, you can see that the values in column 7 are the same as those in column 0, the ones in column 1 the same as those in column 6, in other words: the ones in column `n` are the same as those in column `7 - n`.

Comment: @L.T, it is usual that you *accept* the best solution. Accepting is clicking the `V` shaped icon under the score (left of the answer). And if you want to upvote my answer too, please do that (click the upward showing triangle left of the answer)

Comment: I will do that in a second, you are really helping me out well. However, I'm still a bit confused about the column * 5 + row + 1 part. In the first row (the 1).. You multiply that by 5 and then add the row count + 1, that doesn't make 6 anymore? Same for the other rows. I'm sorry if this may be a stupid question. Arrays are complicated for me.

Comment: @L.T: 5 * 0 + 0 + 1 = 1. Rows and columns start at 0. Last entry on the left side: 5 * 3 + 4 + 1 = 20.

Comment: Ah indeed, I get it now. Thanks alot for the time and effort, I really appreciate it. I've ticked your answer as the correct answer and upvoted it, because I'm new the upvot won't be displayed publically though.

Comment: @L.T: Yes, it should show publicly. Try again.

Comment: it does not. It says 'thanks for your feedback, votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score, I'm sorry. it's recorded atleast.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway.